# Blazor displays ¤ instead of $ when using ToString("C")

Tags: localization, blazor

I'm building a Blazor Web app (wasm). I use ToString("C") to display values as a currency, however the dollar sign is showing up as ¤, for example `¤4.83` instead of `$4.83`. According to Wikipedia "The currency sign ¤ is a character used to denote an unspecified currency"

This seems like a localization issue, but my browser / Blazor is not detecting that I'm en-US and showing the $ sign. How can I show the correct currency symbol?

I'm currently using .Net 5, but this problem exists on .Net core 3.x as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to startup. I only saw this behaviour when I switched to (WSL 2)

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: That worked. Also had to add <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData> in the .csproject

Comment: Yeah the 2 lines combined resolve the issue