# Blazor Server not displaying special characters

Tags: html, blazor

I have a website whereby someone can create a blog post and the information is stored to the database.
One user used some type of font (I presume they copied elsewhere), when the data was stored, the database stored it as so:

ðŽðð‹ðˆðð„ ð–ðŽð‘ðŠ ð…ð‘ðŽðŒ ð‡ðŽðŒð„

When initially coding the website, I used php, when displaying the content I just called a function saved it to a variable called $post and displayed it using $post["title"], the following output occured:

However, now that I am switching from php to Blazor C#, when displaying this it shows like the way it is saved in the database.

How can one overcome such issue, I've MarkupString, I've tried Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(post.title))

None of what I've tried has worked.

Comment: Maybe this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67428902/blazor-displays-%c2%a4-instead-of-when-using-tostringc/67438832#67438832

Comment: @BrianParker I'm using Blazor Server, not WASM